# Is it safe to maintain state in IConvention implementing multiple convention types?

Tags: entity-framework-core

What I am essentially wondering is, if I create a new instance of an `IConvention` which implements `IModelFinalizingConvention` and `IModelFinalizedConvention` within my `IConventionSetPlugin.ModifyConventions` method, is that instance only intended to be used to create one and only one model?

Another way of asking might be, if I gather some state within `ProcessModelFinalizing` and store it in the class instance, will the next call of `ProcessModelFinalized` be for the same model?

I'm mostly concerned about some strange race condition which might happen if an instance of an `IConvention` is shared between threads where the state in my instance gets modified within `ProcessModelFinalized` and then `ProcessModelFinalized` gets called again from another thread.

My reading of the source is that this should not happen.  It looks to me like a new convention set gets called every time a new model is needed and that convention set is discarded once the model is finalized.  However, I was just hoping to get some reinforcement of this.